# dijit contentpane content containing attach points

Tags: javascript, html, dojo, contentpane

something like this:

```
var cp = new ContentPane({
                    title: self.friends_data.data[index].name,
                    closable: true,
                    onClose:function(){
                        conf = confirm("Do you really want to Close this?");
                        if (conf){
                            self.friends_tabs[index] = null;
                            return true;
                        }
                        return false;
                    },
                    content: newTabTemplate
                });
```

where `newTabTemplate` is:

```
<div>
            <span data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.AccordionContainer" style="min-width: 1em; min-height: 1em; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
              <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="Write testimonial for friend" doLayout="false">
                <div data-dojo-type="dijit.Editor" data-dojo-attach-point="editor" data-dojo-props="onChange:function(){console.log('editor1 onChange handler: ' + arguments[0])}, extraPlugins:['foreColor','hiliteColor','fontName', 'fontSize', 'formatBlock', 'createLink', 'unlink', 'insertImage', {name: 'fullscreen', zIndex: 900}]" height=90% style=""></div>
                <!--
                dojo.connect(dijit.registry.byNode(editor1.toolbar.containerNode.children[editor1.toolbar.containerNode.children.length-1]), "onChange", function(x){alert('hello')});
              -->
              </div>
              <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="Read their testimonial for you" doLayout="false">
              </div>
            </span>
</div>
```

Now, I want `cp.editor` to work because in there is an attach point named `editor` in cp's template. but it says `undefined`. Any way around that?

The instantiation happens correctly i.e. the visual output is correct, only attach point is not working.

Comment: How is the dojo parser invoked? `parseOnLoad=?` in the HTML or do you parse explicitly yourself?

Comment: @PaulGrime `parseOnLoad=true` in dojo config. So no explicit parsing

Comment: Can you try turning off parseOnLoad and parsing yourself? Maybe attach points only work for custom widgets, else you might have to mix-in this functionality into your `cp` object - https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin.html.

Comment: Ok, the mixin method worked. Add it as an answer, I'll accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the widgets-in-template functionality to `cp` as a mix-in, as I believe `ContentPane` does not have this functionality by default.

https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin.html

Comment: so I defined a custom widget extending from `ContentPane` and set its `templateString` accordingly. Simple!